# ListView, notifyDataSetChanged() crashes : Error inflating class element

Tags: android, listview

If I attempt to update my ListView with an array containing anything, I get an error on Binary XML file line #8. That's where the 'fragment' element begins, and that runs fine as long as I don't try to update my ListView.

Error :

```
02-11 04:12:58.818 8311-8311/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.example.kit.myapplication, PID: 8311
                                                 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:378)
                                                     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:369)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2346)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1875)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:702)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1670)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2148)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                     at android.widget.TableLayout.onLayout(TableLayout.java:445)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:435)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2678)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16630)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5437)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                    at android.vi
```

(activity_maps.xml):

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapActivity"
    android:id="@+id/Frame">

    <fragment xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="254dp"
            android:choiceMode="none"
            android:id="@+id/testList" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawable="@drawable/round_shape_button"
            android:text="@string/lookupButton"
            android:id="@+id/lookupButton"
            android:onClick="onClick" />

    </TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="303dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/pleasewaitforgps"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#c8ffffff"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="false"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#c9000000"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="332dp"
        android:layout_height="447dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:id="@+id/addressFrame"
        android:visibility="invisible">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="303dp"
            android:layout_height="422dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/addressString"
            android:id="@+id/addressLabel"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Relevant Code :

```
    private ListView mListView;    
    ArrayList<String> mListItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        try {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);    
            mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.testList);
            mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_maps, mListItems);
            mListItems.add("anything");
            mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

**Update** : Added full XML

Comment: Is your Activity extend `FragmentActivity` ?

Comment: post your activity_map.xml

Comment: Nay, it extends AppCompatActivity. the full class declaration is this : 
- 
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, View.OnClickListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback {

Comment: @CodeMinion Do what i said

Comment: @MD but how will I suppress the Action Bar from a Fragment Activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait. Why are you using the activity layout as your listview layout?

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_maps, mListItems);
```

I believe the problem lies with your ArrayAdapter trying to create its view from the xml layout.

> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_maps,
>   mListItems);

What type of ListView layout are you trying to make?

If your list view item only require a single row text, you can use the layout created by Android.

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
```

Comment: I'm kind of new to Android dev, the ListView in question occupies the lower half of the screen, it's not a ListViewLayout

Comment: How would your listview look like? This is important because based on your current code, you're telling each row of your listview to generate a view that is exactly the same as your activity. And I believe the error occur because the list view xml parser doesn't know the fragment tag.

Comment: I'm just trying to add simple text extries to my ListView, how should I be going about this?

Comment: Multiple, but one at a time

Comment: I looked up the ArrayAdapter constructor, I see what I've been doing wrong now. I've been adapting code from samples I can find and making bad assumptions :P

Comment: Yes. The constructor expect a resource id of a layout in order to generate the view for a single row.

Comment: Thanks for drawing my attention to the problem!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong layout in arrayadapter

Change your

```
  mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.activity_maps, mListItems);
```

to

```
mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, mListItems);
```